# How to properly cancel a realtime multiplayer match?

Tags: android, google-play-games

How to properly cancel a realtime multiplayer match if the user cancels the match during the waiting room phase? At this time, there isn't a "room id" to call the `leave` API.

First a quick game is created:

```
Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);
RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = configRoom();
roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);
```

Then `onRoomCreated` is triggered and a waiting room is showed:

```
Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(getApiClient(), room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
```

After that the user presses back, canceling the match. Then `onActivityResult` is triggered with `RC_WAITING_ROOM` and `responseCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

The problem is that the match is still there, waiting for another player. If someone also starts a quick game 10 minutes later, the game will start!

How do I clean it after the user cancels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onActivityResult` extra has the room information (even when it is canceled):

```
Room room = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_ROOM);
```

Then you just need to leave the room:

```
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, room.getRoomId());
```